# Spark Streaming and Phoenix Kerberos issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, spark-streaming, kerberos, apache-phoenix

Sorry for this question as this has been raised numerous time on SO, But I am still not able to find a solution for my issue after going through each relevant post.
I am using Spark Streaming (1.6.1) with Phoenix (4.4) on Kerberos env on HDP 2.4.2 getting below exception when try to read or write from HBase. I get the same issue even after skipping key-ph.conf file from spark-submit.

I had a look on below post which has identical problem as mine but still I am not able to find solution for my issue:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/56848/spark-cant-connect-to-secure-phoenix.html

[Spark can't connect to secure phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532384/spark-cant-connect-to-secure-phoenix)

Below is my Spark-submit command.

```
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--master yarn-cluster \
--num-executors 2  \
--executor-memory 8g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=1024m  \
--files key-ph.conf#key-ph.conf,user.headless.keytab#user.headless.keytab,/etc/hbase/2.4.2.0-258/0/hbase-site.xml \
--jars /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/lib/phoenix-core-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-client-spark.jar \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./key-ph.conf -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy-host -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy-host -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-phoenix-driver.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./key-ph.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-phoenix-executor.properties" \
--class com.spark.demo.SampleInsert /home/user/test-ph.jar tableName ZK_IP:2181:/hbase-secure:user@CLIENT.LAN:/home/user/user.headless.keytab
```

Spark Code:

```
 demoArrDataFrame.write
        .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
        .options(Map("table" -> tableName.toUpperCase,
          "zkUrl" -> "ZK_IP:2181:/hbase-secure:user@FORSYS.LAN:/home/user/user.headless.keytab"))
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .save

16/12/05 16:11:36 WARN AbstractRpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
16/12/05 16:11:36 ERROR AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1711)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:550)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:810)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1174)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:112)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1974)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:770)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:305)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:295)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1244)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1850)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1819)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1819)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:180)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:132)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:99)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:82)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:70)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getUpsertColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:232)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:45)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this issue by performing below steps as follows:

1) Pass required hbase,phoenix jars into spark extra classpath option:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar" \

--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar" \
```

2) Valid keytab and jaas conf in spark extra java options:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf -Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXY.IP -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXY.IP2 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" \

--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf" \
```

kafka-jaas.conf file as an example:

```
KafkaServer {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab"
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=false
   serviceName="kafka"
   principal="kafka/IP@REALM.LAN";
};
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useTicketCache=true
   renewTicket=true
   serviceName="kafka";
};
Client {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab"
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=false
   serviceName="zookeeper"
   principal="kafka/IP@REALM.LAN";
};
```

3) Configuring --files spark options

```
--files kafka_jaas.conf#kafka_jaas.conf,user.headless.keytab#user.headless.keytab,/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml#hbase-site.xml \
```

After following the steps if you are still not able to connect to secured phoenix. Please set below SPARK_CLASSPATH and then run/execute spark-submit command.

```
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your issue has been solved, but I believe it can help who is still facing the same problem.

[Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#long-running-applications) says:

> Long-Running Applications Long-running applications may run into issues if their run time exceeds the maximum delegation token lifetime
>   configured in services it needs to access.
>
> Spark supports automatically creating new tokens for these
>   applications when running in YARN mode. **Kerberos credentials need to
>   be provided to the Spark application via the spark-submit command,
>   using the --principal and --keytab parameters**.
>
> The provided keytab will be copied over to the machine running the
>   Application Master via the Hadoop Distributed Cache. For this reason,
>   it’s strongly recommended that both YARN and HDFS be secured with
>   encryption, at least.
>
> The Kerberos login will be periodically renewed using the provided
>   credentials, and new delegation tokens for supported will be created.

Follow bellow the example of a working spark-submit:

```
    spark-submit -v \
    --principal ${keytabPrincipal} \
    --keytab ${keytabPath} \
    --files ${configDir}/log4j-bdfsap.properties#log4j-bdfsap.properties,${configDir}/jaas.conf#jaas.conf,hdfs:///apps/spark/lib/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4.jar#spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4.jar,hdfs:///apps/hive/conf/hive-site.xml#hive-site.xml,hdfs:///apps/spark/lib/elasticsearch-spark_2.10-2.4.0.jar#elasticsearch-spark_2.10-2.4.0.jar  \
    --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-bdfsap.properties" \
 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=8" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=1h" \
    --conf "spark.task.maxFailures=8" \
    --conf "spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true" \
    --jars hdfs:///apps/spark/lib/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4.jar,hdfs:///apps/spark/lib/elasticsearch-spark_2.10-2.4.0.jar \
    --name ${APP_NAME} \
    --class ${APP_CLASS} \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --driver-cores ${DRIVER_CORES} \
    --driver-memory ${DRIVER_MEMORY} \
    --num-executors ${NUM_EXECUTORS} \
    --executor-memory ${EXECUTOR_MEMORY} \
    --executor-cores ${EXECUTOR_CORES} \
    --queue ${queueNameSparkStreaming} \
    ${APP_LIB_HDFS_PATH} ${APP_CONF_HDFS_PATH}/${LOAD_CONF_FILE}
```

jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab="./user.keytab"
  useTicketCache=false
  serviceName="kafka"
  principal="user@BRUBLES";
};
```