# Spark can't connect to secure phoenix

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I am running a spark program on secured cluster which creates SqlContext for creating dataframe over phoenix table.

When I run my program in local mode with --master option set to local[2] my program works completely fine, however when I try to run same program with master option set to yarn-client, I am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=5, exceptions:
Fri Sep 16 12:14:10 IST 2016, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1474008247898, pause=100, retries=5}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to demo-qa2-nn/10.60.2.15:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:550)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:810)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to demo-qa2-nn/10.60.2.15:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1711)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to demo-qa2-nn/10.60.2.15:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1531)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to demo-qa2-nn/10.60.2.15:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$1.run(RpcClientImpl.java:679)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(RpcClientImpl.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:745)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:737)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
        ... 76 more
```

PFB program and command I am using:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
      .set("spark.kyro.registrationRequired", "true") //always use kyro 
    CustomKryoRegistrator.register(sparkConf)

val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString", "true")

val df = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
          .option("table", table_name)
          .option("zkUrl", "demo-qa2-dn03,demo-qa2-dn01,demo-qa2-dn02")
      .load()

df.show();
```

Command:

```
spark-submit --jars $(echo ./lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ','),$(echo ./conf/*.* | tr ' ' ','),/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-thin-client.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/lib/phoenix-core-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/lib/phoenix-spark-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-client.jar --driver-class-path $(echo ./lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ','),$(echo ./conf/*.* | tr ' ' ','),/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/lib/phoenix-spark-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/lib/phoenix-core-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-thin-client.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-client.jar --master yarn-client --class com.xyz.demo.dq.DataQualityApplicationHandler tr-dq-16.7.0.0.0.jar org ss1 Phoenix tr-dq-job.properties QUALITY
```

I added hbase-site.xml in spark conf directory on all nodes and restarted spark service but it didn't works. Also hbas-site.xml is already present in my classpath.

My Phoenix version is 4.4 and spark version is 1.6.

Also I followed workaround given in [PHOENIX-2817](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-2817) and tried upgrading phoenix to 4.8, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is there any Phoenix parameter about managing automatically the Kerberos ticket **in each Spark executor**? If no, then have a look at that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332026/issue-scala-code-in-spark-shell-to-retrieve-data-from-hbase

Comment: After adding hbase jars in spark.driver.extraClassPath  my job is working fine.

Root Cause: 
When spark-submit detects YARN cluster deployment mode, org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client is used for app submission. While getting HBASE_DELEGATION_TOKEN yarn was not getting HBase jars. Hence SPARK_CLASSPATH should be configured with required Hbase jars, so that yarn will get it while taking delegation token.
Note: Starting from spark 1.5, spark.driver.extraClasspath need to be set instead of exporting SPARK_CLASSPATH.

Comment: Fine - but please update the title of your question to "**[Solved]** Spark can't connect..." to make it clear that you don't expect any answer now  :-)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: what? No, that is *forum* etiquette. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it is a site for Questions and Answers. On Stack Overflow, you can submit an answer even if you asked the question yourself. Then mark it "Acceoted" to indicate this solved the problem.

Comment: Please check this post..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977866/spark-streaming-and-phoenix-kerberos-issue/43848748#43848748